# How can I horizontally center the content of a div inside another div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have following code (you can ignore the actual content as the doubt is only concerned with layout):

Here is the output:

[image]

There are two components a pie chart and a table. Both have class set `ccol-lg-6`. I want pie chart to horizontally center in its column. But it is right aligned. I tried adding `margin: 0 auto;`. But it did not help. How can I center align the pie chart in its column.

PS: You can see it in action in [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-bush-j7x99d?file=/index.html:1006-1014).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />

  <!-- Learn more about this tag here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <!-- Learn more about this tag here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/compatibility/jj676915(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />

  <!-- Minified bootstrap css  -->
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" /> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.usebootstrap.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <!-- Customized styles -->
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" /> -->

  <title>Static Template</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 2rem;">
      <div class="col-12 col-lg-6" style="padding-top: 25px; margin: 0 auto; position: relative;">
        <div class="vega-embed" role="graphics-document" aria-roledescription="visualization" aria-label="A simple pie chart with embedded data." style="cursor: default; margin: 0 auto; position: relative;">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" class="marks" width="248" height="234" viewBox="0 0 248 234" style="background-color: white;">
                  <g
                    fill="none"
                    stroke-miterlimit="10"
                    transform="translate(28,29)"
                  >
                    <g
                      class="mark-group role-frame root"
                      role="graphics-object"
                      aria-roledescription="group mark container"
                    >
                      <g transform="translate(0,0)">
                        <path
                          class="background"
                          aria-hidden="true"
                          d="M0,0h200v200h-200Z"
                        ></path>
                        <g>
                          <g
                            class="mark-arc role-mark layer_0_marks"
                            role="graphics-object"
                            aria-roledescription="arc mark container"
                          >
                            <path
                              aria-label="angle: 3; color: rgb(121, 199, 227); hover_tooltip: I initiated threads"
                              role="graphics-symbol"
                              aria-roledescription="arc mark"
                              transform="translate(100,100)"
                              d="M39.03892751634948,-92.06498866764288A100,100,0,0,0,6.123233995736766e-15,-100L0,0Z"
                              fill="rgb(121, 199, 227)"
                              fill-opacity="0.8"
                              stroke="black"
                              stroke-width="0"
                            ></path>
                            <path
                              aria-label="angle: 20; color: rgb(26, 49, 119); hover_tooltip: I commented threads"
                              role="graphics-symbol"
                              aria-roledescription="arc mark"
                              transform="translate(100,100)"
                              d="M-1.8369701987210297e-14,-100A100,100,0,0,0,-45.101011921610194,89.25188358598811L0,0Z"
                              fill="rgb(26, 49, 119)"
                              fill-opacity="0.8"
                              stroke="black"
                              stroke-width="0"
                            ></path>
                            <path
                              aria-label="angle: 24; color: rgb(18, 147, 154); hover_tooltip: Rest of threads"
                              role="graphics-symbol"
                              aria-roledescription="arc mark"
                              transform="translate(100,100)"
                              d="M-45.101011921610194,89.25188358598811A100,100,0,1,0,39.03892751634948,-92.06498866764288L0,0Z"
                              fill="rgb(18, 147, 154)"
                              fill-opacity="0.8"
                              stroke="black"
                              stroke-width="0"
                            ></path>
                          </g>
                          <g
                            class="mark-text role-mark layer_1_marks"
                            role="graphics-object"
                            aria-roledescription="text mark container"
                          >
                            <text
                              aria-label="angle: 3; color: rgb(121, 199, 227); hover_tooltip: I initiated threads"
                              role="graphics-symbol"
                              aria-roledescription="text mark"
                              text-anchor="middle"
                              transform="translate(123.90231821246034,-14.59540460439041)"
                              font-family="sans-serif"
                              font-size="11px"
                              fill="black"
                              fill-opacity="0.8"
                              stroke-width="0"
                            >
                              3
                            </text>
                            <text
                              aria-label="angle: 20; color: rgb(26, 49, 119); hover_tooltip: I commented threads"
                              role="graphics-symbol"
                              aria-roledescription="text mark"
                              text-anchor="middle"
                              transform="translate(-16.731039651804466,75.18158196789659)"
                              font-family="sans-serif"
                              font-size="11px"
                              fill="black"
                              fill-opacity="0.8"
                              stroke-width="0"
                            >
                              20
                            </text>
                            <text
                              aria-label="angle: 24; color: rgb(18, 147, 154); hover_tooltip: Rest of threads"
                              role="graphics-symbol"
                              aria-roledescription="text mark"
                              text-anchor="middle"
                              transform="translate(208.8509096481209,153.51217149140018)"
                              font-family="sans-serif"
                              font-size="11px"
                              fill="black"
                              fill-opacity="0.8"
                              stroke-width="0"
                            >
                              24
                            </text>
                          </g>
                        </g>
                        <path
                          class="foreground"
                          aria-hidden="true"
                          d=""
                          display="none"
                        ></path>
                      </g>
                    </g>
                  </g>
                </svg>
          <form class="vega-bindings"></form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center" style="padding-left: 0px;">
        <h6 style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">
          I Participation
        </h6>
        <table class="statstable">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Action</th>
              <th>Threads (Total = 47)</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="text-left">
                <div class="d-inline-block" style="
                          background-color: rgb(121, 199, 227);
                          height: 16px;
                          width: 16px;
                          margin-right: 10px;
                        "></div>
                I initiated
              </td>
              <td>3 (6%)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="text-left">
                <div class="d-inline-block" style="
                          background-color: rgb(26, 49, 119);
                          height: 16px;
                          width: 16px;
                          margin-right: 10px;
                        "></div>
                I commented
              </td>
              <td>20 (42%)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="text-left">
                <div class="d-inline-block" style="
                          background-color: rgb(18, 147, 154);
                          height: 16px;
                          width: 16px;
                          margin-right: 10px;
                        "></div>
                Rest
              </td>
              <td>24 (51%)</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->
  <!-- <script src="https://cdn.usebootstrap.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `text-center` on the column does just fine. Other notes... You're writing styles for many things that Bootstrap already provides. Look over [the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/introduction/) again to get more familiar with what's available. Also, use custom classes instead of inline styles, which make future development by you and others much more difficult.